# how to compare two datetime in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I need to show the names of the oldest employee and of the last one so i need to compare datetime of the **hire_date**, here's how i tried and its not working:

```
SELECT ename
from emp
where hiredate = 'MIN(hiredate)' AND hiredate = 'MAX(hiredate)';
```

what should i do?

Comment: Well, _that_ is not working because you are not comparing data in the table.  You are comparing two literal character strings.  That's because you enclosed MIN(hiredate) and MAX(hiredate) in single quotes, making them literal strings.  You might was well said _where hiredate = 'my name is fred' andhiredate = 'my name is joe'_    :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
SQL> with minimax as
  2    (select min(hiredate) min_hiredate,
  3            max(hiredate) max_hiredate
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select e.ename, e.hiredate
  7  from emp e join minimax m on e.hiredate in (m.min_hiredate, m.max_hiredate);

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ----------
SMITH      17.12.1980
ADAMS      12.01.1983

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*,
        rank() over(order by hire_date) rn_asc,
        rank() over(order by hire_date desc) rn_desc
    from emp e
) e
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

The subquery ranks employees by increasing and decreasing hire date, the the outer query selects the top and bottom records. This allows ties, if any.

The same logic can be implemented with a window min and a window max:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*,
        min(hire_date) over() min_hire_date,
        max(hire_date) over() max_hire_date
    from emp e
) e
where hire_date in (min_hire_date, max_hire_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can do this with a "simple" aggregation query:

```
select max(ename) keep (dense_rank first order by hiredate asc) as oldest_employee,
       max(ename) keep (dense_rank first order by hiredate desc) as newest_employee
from emp;
```

You can also use `union all` if you want this information on different rows:

```
(select name, hiredate
 from emp
 order by hiredate
 fetch first 1 row only
) union all
(select name, hiredate
 from emp
 order by hiredate desc
 fetch first 1 row only
);
```